# How to set value for preparedStatement?

Tags: java

I have a preparedStatement which is `select = "Select * From Withdraw where CustID = ? AND AccountNo = ?;";`
how do I get the value to pass from user input into it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String query = "Select * From Withdraw where CustID = ? AND AccountNo = ?";
PreparedStatment preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(query);

preparedStatement.setString(1, aString);
preparedStatement.setString(2, anotherString);

rset = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
```

If you using integers, there is `setInt(1, someInt)`

The 1 argument is the `?`. 1 for first `?`, 2 for the second `?`

```
"... CustID = ? AND AccountNo = ? ..."
              1                 2
```

Comment: thanks, but what is the number "1" means?

Comment: Reread the answer, I explain it.

Comment: does it means that I should write like this:
preparedStatement.setString(1, accNo);
preparedStatement.setString(2, custID);

Comment: Yes, only if `accNo` and `custId` are strings. If they are integers, use `setInt()`

Comment: And `custId` should be 1 and `accNo` should be 2